# Video as a background image not working in Gatsby PWA on iOS

Tags: service-worker, mp4, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I created a opt-in app for potential interims for our company, i worked with Gatsby and for now am quite satisfied with the result. I made it an Progressive Web App as that is fairly easy with the gatsby plugin.

The PWA works great on Android and shows the background video as expected, but on iOS the video doesn't show.

I updated all the packages and dependencies to the last versions but that doesn't change a thing. I tried googling the issue but got a lot of search results off people trying to let a PWA play video in the background when the app is closed (not my case).

```
{
   resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Afstuderen bij Arcady`,
        short_name: `Afstuderen`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#FFF`,
        theme_color: `#00a667`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `src/images/bear_green.png`,
      },
},
'gatsby-plugin-offline',
```

And the content of the service worker

```
importScripts("workbox-v3.6.3/workbox-sw.js");
workbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: "workbox-v3.6.3"});

workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({prefix: "gatsby-plugin-offline"});

workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

/**
 * The workboxSW.precacheAndRoute() method efficiently caches and responds to
 * requests for URLs in the manifest.
 */
self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "url": "webpack-runtime-aec2408fe3a97f1352af.js"
  },
  {
    "url": "app-5b624d17337895ddf874.js"
  },
  {
    "url": "component---node-modules-gatsby-plugin-offline-app-shell-js-b97c345e19bb442c644f.js"
  },
  {
    "url": "offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/index.html",
    "revision": "ac0d57f6ce61fac4bfa64e7e08d076c2"
  },
  {
    "url": "0-d2c3040ae352cda7b69f.js"
  },
  {
    "url": "component---src-pages-404-js-cf647f7c3110eab2f912.js"
  },
  {
    "url": "static/d/285/path---404-html-516-62a-0SUcWyAf8ecbYDsMhQkEfPzV8.json"
  },
  {
    "url": "static/d/604/path---offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback-a-30-c5a-BawJvyh36KKFwbrWPg4a4aYuc8.json"
  },
  {
    "url": "manifest.webmanifest",
    "revision": "5a580d53785b72eace989a49ea1e24f7"
  }
].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/(\.js$|\.css$|static\/)/, workbox.strategies.cacheFirst(), 'GET');
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https?:.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg|gif|tiff|js|woff|woff2|json|css)$/, workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate(), 'GET');
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https?:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/css/, workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate(), 'GET');

/* global importScripts, workbox, idbKeyval */

importScripts(`idb-keyval-iife.min.js`)
const WHITELIST_KEY = `custom-navigation-whitelist`

const navigationRoute = new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(({ event }) => {
  const { pathname } = new URL(event.request.url)

  return idbKeyval.get(WHITELIST_KEY).then((customWhitelist = []) => {
    // Respond with the offline shell if we match the custom whitelist
    if (customWhitelist.includes(pathname)) {
      const offlineShell = `/offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/index.html`
      const cacheName = workbox.core.cacheNames.precache

      return caches.match(offlineShell, { cacheName }).then(cachedResponse => {
        if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse

        console.error(
          `The offline shell (${offlineShell}) was not found ` +
            `while attempting to serve a response for ${pathname}`
        )

        return fetch(offlineShell).then(response => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return caches.open(cacheName).then(cache =>
              // Clone is needed because put() consumes the response body.
              cache.put(offlineShell, response.clone()).then(() => response)
            )
          } else {
            return fetch(event.request)
          }
        })
      })
    }

    return fetch(event.request)
  })
})

workbox.routing.registerRoute(navigationRoute)

let updatingWhitelist = null

function rawWhitelistPathnames(pathnames) {
  if (updatingWhitelist !== null) {
    // Prevent the whitelist from being updated twice at the same time
    return updatingWhitelist.then(() => rawWhitelistPathnames(pathnames))
  }

  updatingWhitelist = idbKeyval
    .get(WHITELIST_KEY)
    .then((customWhitelist = []) => {
      pathnames.forEach(pathname => {
        if (!customWhitelist.includes(pathname)) customWhitelist.push(pathname)
      })

      return idbKeyval.set(WHITELIST_KEY, customWhitelist)
    })
    .then(() => {
      updatingWhitelist = null
    })

  return updatingWhitelist
}

function rawResetWhitelist() {
  if (updatingWhitelist !== null) {
    return updatingWhitelist.then(() => rawResetWhitelist())
  }

  updatingWhitelist = idbKeyval.set(WHITELIST_KEY, []).then(() => {
    updatingWhitelist = null
  })

  return updatingWhitelist
}

const messageApi = {
  whitelistPathnames(event) {
    let { pathnames } = event.data

    pathnames = pathnames.map(({ pathname, includesPrefix }) => {
      if (!includesPrefix) {
        return `${pathname}`
      } else {
        return pathname
      }
    })

    event.waitUntil(rawWhitelistPathnames(pathnames))
  },

  resetWhitelist(event) {
    event.waitUntil(rawResetWhitelist())
  },
}

self.addEventListener(`message`, event => {
  const { gatsbyApi } = event.data
  if (gatsbyApi) messageApi[gatsbyApi](event)
})
```

I expect the iOS PWA (safari) to show the video as it does on Android but instead it gives a grey screen.

I hope some one can help me out or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your video ?

Last time I checked, iOS has a limit of 50MB for the cache of a PWA, so if your video is bigger than 50MB, that may be the reason it works only on Android (which doesn't have such restrictions).

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog post](https://philna.sh/blog/2018/10/23/service-workers-beware-safaris-range-request/) that helped me fix this problem

To add Range request handling to `gatsby-plugin-offline`, I added a script called `range-request-handler.js` with the following:

```js
// range-request-handler.js

// Define workbox globally
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js');

// Bring in workbox libs
const { registerRoute } = require('workbox-routing');
const { CacheFirst } = require('workbox-strategies');
const { RangeRequestsPlugin } = require('workbox-range-requests'); // The fix

// Add Range Request support to fetching videos from cache
registerRoute(
    /(\.webm$|\.mp4$)/,
    new CacheFirst({
        plugins: [
            new RangeRequestsPlugin(),
        ],
    })
);
```

Then in my `gatsby-config.js` I configured the plugin to append the above script:

```js
// gatsby-config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...plugins
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-offline',
      options: {
        appendScript: require.resolve('./range-request-handler.js'),
      },
    },
    // ...plugins
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Videos now work in the Safari browser for me. If there is a better way to implement this, I am all ears. For now it works as intended